# How can prevent browser from stopping php script

Tags: php, xml, browser, connection

I'm making a PHP script which updates my database using a XML file. When i use a small XML file(+-1000 products) the update script works perfectly. When I’m trying to update a bigger XML file(10.000+ products) the browser shuts down the connection after some time. How can i prevent the browser from shutting down the connection?

Comment: `browser shuts down the connection` How did you arrive to this conclusion ? Did you get any error messages ?

Comment: you may need to adjust upload size and execution time in php.ini

Comment: chrome shows me a broken smily page with the text no data received

Comment: i tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); but still shutting down

Comment: take a look at the apache error_log

Comment: It seems OK in the error_log. Can't find anything strange

Comment: try ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

Comment: nope not still not working :(